# How can I reset the top header bar?

Tags: interface

How can I get reset the top header bar in blender? I accidentally used the corner grabbers in that header, and it created a duplicate menu.

In the picture I've included, you can see that I now have 4 duplicates of this menu in a row.  The UI seems to reset itself if I open a new blender file, but I'd prefer to keep this particular blender file in clean, working order...

[image: duplicate header bars i can't get rid of!]

Answer (score 1):

If you drag the corner of one onto the body of the next it will merge them back together.

Answer (score 0):

Hover your mouse over the vertical line that splits the two header bars.  The cursor should change to a horizontal double-arrow.  Right click, and select "Join Area" from the menu.  Then click anywhere on the header bar left of the split point to join the two back into one.

I realize this is more complicated than @Danial's answer, but somehow I find this one easier to remember.  It works better with larger areas, where you can see the join arrow appear.  But yes, it takes more clicks, so use whichever one you like.