# Blender UI not displaying correctly, has anyone seen this before?

Tags: interface

I'm fairly new to Blender, I didn't use it for a short while and when I went back to it, it didn't seem to look right. The top menu is completely covered and the curser doesn't click where it says it is. I've put some screenshots below to try and explain.

Below is the entire screen:

[image: ![Blender not displaying correctly]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZqvC.png)

When you put the curser over edit on the left hand side it selects the mirror function instead, like the curser is in the wrong place.

Any help with why this is happening would be most appreciated.

Comment: "*has anyone seen this before?*" Yes, you would too if you used search before asking https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligned Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62784/how-can-i-reset-the-top-header-bar

Comment: Thanks for the link! Sorry, I tried searching but wasn't sure what to search really. Thanks for all the help :)